# Не выводится progressBar

Tags: android

Подгружаю данные с сервера порциями и вывожу списком. При прокрутке списка до низу начинается новая подгрузка. Хочу, чтобы в этот момент внизу появлялась панелька, на которой располагался бы `progressBar` и небольшой текст "`loading...`" Подгружаю данные с помощью `AsyncTask`.
Пытался вызывать в методе `onPreExecute()`

```
        proBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        proBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        edText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar_text);
        edText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

и выклчючать в `onPostExecute`, но ничего не выводится, почему? 
Вот так выглядит лэйаут:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<!-- Данные списком -->

<ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
/>
```

<!-- Панель с progressBar и комментом -->

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <!-- Прогресс-бар и коммент -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar_text"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="loading search engines..."
            android:ems="10" >
         </EditText>
    </LinearLayout> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. У **ListView** есть замечательное свойство, **FooterView** называется. [Пример кода](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265228/how-to-add-footer-in-list-view)
2. Уж если хочется все таки свой велосипед написать, то я бы сделал так:

   ```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">
       <RelativeLayout 
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/progress_view"/>
       <ListView 
           android:layout_above="@id/progress_view"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:id="@+id/listview"/>

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
3. Еще как вариант можно в адаптере для **ListView** в методе **getSize()** возвращать на единицу больше, а в методе **getView()** проверять позицию элемента, если она равна последней, то инфлейтить вьюху с прогрессом, если нет, то обычную вьюху

**UPDATE**

Для твоего случая вот рабочий код

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<LinearLayout 
    android:background="#aaa"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0">

    <ProgressBar 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text_text_text"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: скорее всего тебе достаточно будет в LinearLayout, который идет сразу после ListView, добавить свойство layout_height = 1 или 0, одно из этого поможет

Comment: сделал так, но эффекта не вижу
прокрутка есть, а progressBar не видно..

Comment: Добавил рабочий код к своему ответу

Comment: @Роман Захаров, А как сделать так, чтобы рядом выводилось небольшое текстовое сообщение?   
Вот добавил рядом с progressBar TextView, а толку 0

Comment: Обновил свой ответ для TextView

Comment: ага, все получилось, спасибо! 
тут еще такая штука: если отваливает инет на телефоне или еще что-то такое хочу сделать так, чтобы, если не получилось загрузить данные, то появлялось сообщение о том, что не удалось подгрузить и была кнопка "try again" 
добавил кнопку, как сделать так, чтобы подгрузка начиналась заново при нажатии на кнопку?

Comment: ну тут тебе надо просто запомнить предыдущие параметры, с которыми ты запускал AsyncTask, а потом в onClickListener обработать нажатие на кнопку эту, запустив там свой AsyncTask с сохраненными параметрами

Comment: я просто хотел чередовать в зависимости от ситуации то progressBar, то эту кнопку... и отслеживать все это в onPostExecute